# ssh to debian 11 takes almost 2 min

Tags: ssh, debian, debian-bullseye

this is what I see in the syslog - the ssh is being done with Private key.
after 2 minutes - login succesfull.

```
Feb  8 10:01:53 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 0...
Feb  8 10:01:53 systemd[34555]: gpgconf: error running '/usr/lib/gnupg/scdaemon': probably not installed
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Killing process 34555 (gpgconf) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Killing process 34556 (awk) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Killing process 34561 (dirmngr) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Killing process 34555 (gpgconf) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Killing process 34556 (awk) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Killing process 34561 (dirmngr) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: user@0.service: Unit process 34561 (dirmngr) remains running after unit stopped.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: Failed to start User Manager for UID 0.
Feb  8 10:03:23 systemd[1]: Started Session 14 of user root.
```

Comment: Provide the verbose output of your ssh command and the relevant entries from the sshd logs on your server.

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=980838

Comment: So it's a known bug ? and that's what causes the 90 seconds delay ? amazing it wasn't fixed yet

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - where can I find sshd logs ? ssh just hangs until the the attempt to start User Manager finishes. what is User Manager ? can I disable it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/pam.d/common-session

#session optional pam_systemd.so

will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled packages **gpg-agent** and **dirmngr**, which were causing problems.

I don't know if they were installed automatically or installed as a dependency, but they were not needed in my system.

This is not solution for everyone, so I don't want to write a command for removing packages here.